# Enzyme unable to find children rendered inside React Apollo Query components

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, graphql, enzyme, react-apollo

Can you tell me how to test apollo query components with Enzyme. The query uses `isomorphic-fetch` to fetch data from the database. Here's my example test code:

```
describe('Query', async () => {

    it('exists',  async () => {

        let wrapper = await mount(
            (
                <TestProvider>
                    <Query query={gql`...`}>
                        {
                           ({data:{something}})=>
                                 <CustomComponent something={something} />
                        }
                    </Query>
                </TestProvider>
            )
        );
        // return false
        expect(wrapper.find(CustomComponent).exists()).to.be.true
    })
});
```

Why can't Enzyme find the `CustomComponent` inside the Query component? However, the following example would work when the children isn't a function:

```
describe('Component', async () => {
    it('exists',  async () => {
        let wrapper = await mount(
            (
                <TestProvider>
                    <div><CustomButton/></div>
                </TestProvider>
            )
        );
        // return true
        expect(wrapper.find(CustomButton).exists()).to.be.true
    })
});
```

Comment: One way to debug this is to log the wrapper object or use a debugger to inspect it. Then you could confirm that the element is actually not rendered.

Comment: @Herku, the problem is that I couldn't find a way to wait for apollo finishes fetching data from the server and rendering before the `expect` function triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using the classic callback would work, see below.

I am not sure about the general testing strategy with apollo here. This is maybe something where UI tests would be much better. When you want to test your components in unit tests (which for e.g. we do very seldom at work) only test the components itself, not the queries inside. With the new render prop API of React Apollo this has become much more difficult but in my opinion this is because it is very unpopular to unit tests components in that sense. Alternatively you can have a look into [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library) that has a function that is called [waitForElement](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library#waitforelement) and behaves a bit more than assertions in UI tests like in cypress.

```
it('exists',  done => {

    let wrapper = await mount(
        (
            <TestProvider>
                <Query query={gql`...`}>
                    {
                       ({data:{something}})=> {
                           process.nextTick(check);
                           return <CustomComponent something={something} />;
                    }
                </Query>
            </TestProvider>
        )
    );
    function check() {
      expect(wrapper.find(CustomComponent).exists()).to.be.true
      done();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my temporary solution for async rendering in enzyme. I have to use `wrapper.updated()` in every `it` function:

```
describe('Query', () => {

    let wrapper;

    before( ()=>{
        wrapper = mount(
            (
                <TestProvider>
                    <Query query={gql`...`}>
                        {
                           ({data:{something}})=>
                                 <CustomComponent something={something} />
                        }
                    </Query>
                </TestProvider>
            )
        );
    })

    it('exists', done => {
        setTimeout( ()=>{
            wrapper.update();
            console.log(wrapper.debug());
            expect(wrapper.find(CustomImage).length).to.be.above(0);
            done();
        },1000)
    })
});
```

Do you have alternative suggestions? I'd like to avoid using `setTimeout`.